# How to create a new SQLite3 database using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I know how to connect to a database in the current file directory:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'Data.db'
```

My question is how do I create a new database in the current file directory?

**bonus question**: what do the two colons means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file gets created if it doesn't exist.

Bonus: `SQLite3::Database` points to `SQLite3` module's `Database` submodule or subclass.